# Rails overriding default_url_options causes URL's like "localhost:2999:3000/..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

in my setup I've got nginx running on port 3000 acting as a proxy to my rails app running on port 2999. Obviously, I have to have the rails app use 3000 as the port for generated URL's (so that when I use `login_url`, it will generate an url like `http://localhost:3000/login`.

I overrid rails' `default_url_options` like this:

```
def default_url_options( options = {} )
  options.merge( { :only_path => false, :port => 3000 } )
end
```

However, this causes URL's like `http://localhost:2999:3000/login` for `login_path`.

Only thing I found was this ticket describing a related problem: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/1106-rewrite_url-adds-port-twice, but there's nothing helpful in there.

Is there any way to make rails get the URL right?

thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the hostnames for your different environments, you could set them statically, which routes around the problem:

```
# config/environments/production.rb
DEFAULT_HOST_WITH_PORT = 'http://myrealsite.com:3000'

# config/environments/development.rb
DEFAULT_HOST_WITH_PORT = 'http://localhost:3000'

# config/environments/test.rb
DEFAULT_HOST_WITH_PORT = 'http://localhost:3000'
```

and then

```
def default_url_options( options = {} )
  options.merge(:only_path => false, :host => DEFAULT_HOST_WITH_PORT)
end
```

(notice that you're not setting the port separately, you're just counting on it being included in host)

Comment: fortunately, I am in that situation, and it works! Thx for the quick response, I'm gonna use this workaround now (as long as there's not another, less dirty solution) =)

Comment: setting the host_with_port, at least on production, is not as dirty as it sounds... sometimes people come with crazy-looking subdomains (http://outdooractionequipmentmonkeys.brighterplanet.com) and we don't want to write URLs with that.

Comment: Hi, what can I do if there are many subdomains linked to my application? would it work? In what kind of file, am I supposed to store the overriding default_url_options method?  Thx!